# How to insert a uCommerce purchase order with T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I've had a rare case where I have a uCommerce order, which is payed, but doesn't exist anywhere in the db.

So, I have to remake the order from scratch. I do have an existing orderID which I have to use. and I know the different products, I also have the data of the client.

My initial thought was to make a SQL insert query. But after some research I found out that I will have to make an order, orderlines, shipment, client, basket... All this has Guid's and more which I don't know if I can just make them up, or I have to create them with a specific method.

Or if their is another way to do this, that would also be fine.

In short: I want to know how to insert a uCommerce order from SQL.

Comment: Would it be an option to create the order on the web site (just as the customer did), and then change the order number in the database afterwards?

Comment: @lasseeskildsen thanks, this solved it.. kinda. After doing that, I had a better understanding of the workings of the eshop and I actually found the missing order. (It had some missing data, because of an error that happend. And that's why I couldn't find it at first.) So I filled out the missing data and everything is ok again. 
Still, I would like to know how to create an order manually

Comment: guid is just a generated unique identifier, you should be able to generate one and as long as you make sure the key is properly placed into the foreign key or related fields you should be fine.